# Diff is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, momentjs, pikaday

I have the following code and need to calculate the difference between the two dates but why am I getting diff is not a function? Note I am using pikaday.js and moment.js but I have hardcoded the inputs for simplicity. I have seen other similar posts on StackOverflow but I am new to moment.js and need help with the syntax and not just a short sentence as an answer. Thank you in advance.

```html
<div>ARRIVAL</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="txtArrival" value="07/12/18">
</div>
<div>DEPARTURE</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="txtDeparture" value="15/12/18">
</div>
```

```js
var aDate, dDate, a, b, days;

//get arrival and departure
aDate = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('txtArrival'),
  format: 'D MMM YYYY',
  onSelect: function() {
    console.log(aDate.getMoment().format('DD/MM/YY'));
  }
});

dDate = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('txtDeparture'),
  format: 'D MMM YYYY',
  onSelect: function() {
    console.log(dDate.getMoment().format('DD/MM/YY'));
  }
});

//calculate days
a = aDate.getMoment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
d = dDate.getMoment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
days = d.diff(a, 'days');
```

Comment: [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) returns a string, not a moment object, you can't call [`diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) on strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) returns `string` thus the error is expected. You need to use `moment` object and perform `.diff()` on them

*Use*

```
days = dDate.getMoment().diff(aDate.getMoment(), 'days');
```

*instead of*

```
days = d.diff(a, 'days');
```

Comment: Awesome, I was really stuck with that. Thank you!